# The use and difference of simple future perfect tense and simple future perfect continous tense

Tags: grammar

i do not understand the difference of future perect tense and future perect continous in a sentence or paragraph because the time signal of both tense are same. Namely by, before, and when. sometimes I got problem to do homework that determine use future perect tense and future perect continous in sentence.

can you tell me the difference of each sentence?

Comment: Give some examples, did you do any research?

Answer (score -1):

The difference between the two exists not in the substance of the meaning but in the grammatical structure. A future perfect tense is used to refer to events that will take place in the future but in an anticipatory mood. For instance, one can say: I will have worked in this company for 10 years by next January. This is an anticipatory statement. In the case of a future perfect continuous tense, the intention is not anticipatory but deterministic: I will have been working in this company for 10 years by next January. However, the import of both sentences is the same.
Thank you.